# How to optimize Azure Data FactoryPipeline?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

Need help on the below requirement...

I have to perform ADF migration from 90(source and target Azure MI databases)
For Example Source on-prem servers(data server1, data server2, data server3,...data server90) to
Target Azure MI Servers(Azure MI Database1, Azure MI Database2, Azure MI Database3,....Azure MI Database90)

On-Prem dataserver1 db1 (Self Hosted Integration Runtime1)---> Azure MI Database1

My question is, do I need to create 90 (Self Hosted Integrated Runtime for each on-prem source data servers) and 90 pipelines for this similar activity, or is there a way to optimize it so that one self-hosted integration runtime service and same pipeline can be used for all 90 migration?

Any help or suggestion would be a great help as I am new to ADF...

Below are my pipeline activities...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bQTe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoaMd.png)

Comment: Can you show us screenshot of your activity inside ForEach activity?

Comment: In inner activity, we are using stored procedure to transform and load data in target.. Process is copy source data in stage table of target database, transform data by stored procedure, load final data in dbo.<tables> and finally delete all stg schema objects(stg.<tables> and stg.<Proc>)